# CKEditor won't fire change event

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I created an CKEditor instance, but the `change` event won't fire. No matter what changed.

This is what I have:

```
var instance = CKEDITOR.replace('textarea_' + id, {                                                          
    width: 400,                                                                                                                         
    height: 100,                                                                                                                        
    toolbar: [                                                                                                                          
        ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],                                                                                  
        ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll'],                                                                                          
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],                                     
        ['TextColor'],                                                                                                                  
        ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
        ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']                                                                                                    
    ],                                                                                                                                  
    uiColor: '#ededed',                                                                                                                 
    resize_enabled: false                                                                                                               
});                                                                                                                                     

instance.on('change', function (evt) {                                                                                                  
    console.log('changed', evt.editor.getData());                                                                                       
});

instance.on('key', function (evt) {                                                                                                  
    console.log('key', evt.editor.getData());                                                                                       
});
```

For some reason it does not trigger the change event. The `key` event works fine, but is not very helpful because it does not register any format changes.

Is there something missing?

I'm using version 4.1 of CKEditor.

Comment: Which version of CKE do you use?

Comment: see updated answer, it's 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`editor#change`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) event is available since CKEditor 4.2. Update your version of CKEditor.